# Converting htaccess rewrite rule to nginx

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, ddev

I have trouble figuring out how to rewrite this htaccess rule to a nginx rule. It's for a legacy project that uses a static asset version in the url.

The file on the server is for example located in:

`assets/js/jquery.min.js`

The url to fetch it is:

`assets/js/jquery.min.1661243858.js`

The htaccess rule is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*?\/)*?([a-zA-Z\.\-]+)(\d+)\.(bmp|css|cur|gif|ico|jpe?g|js|png|svgz?|webp|webmanifest)$ $1$2$4 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I tried some converters and found a blog post going over this. But it doesn't seem  to be working. I'm using ddev as my environment. Current nginx rule that I set in .ddev/nginx_full/nginx-site.conf, I removed #ddev-generated:

```
location ~* (.+)\.(?:\d+)\.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|webp)$ {
  try_files $uri $1.$2;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you answer your question then with the correct answer and approach.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem was that I assumed doing `ddev start` applied the changes made in `.ddev/nginx_full/nginx-site.conf`. It doesn't. I needed to use `ddev restart`. The nginx rule is correct.